# Functioning issue of angularjs dropdowns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using multiselect dropdowns in angular. The issue am facing is whenever any option is selected in dropdown, automatically the top of dropdown content is being displayed.
For ex; Here i have a `demo`: https://plnkr.co/edit/eGVkSPJRpddeGxcIogdd?p=preview when I check/uncheck Honda option from dropdown,automatically top of dropdown is dispalyed.

How can I make it to stay at the option which i select from dropdown. So that checking/unchecking will be easy for user.

Comment: whats do you mean by automatically top of dropdown is dispalyed? I can see 1 item selected , on selecting any option

Comment: @Deep: Pls see the plunk. if u select any option immediately control goes to first option of dropdown.. which makes it difficult for user to check and uncheck at a time. First user selects an option and top option of dropdown will be displayed.. again user has to scroll down and uncheck.

Comment: Its a focus issue comment out @252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the multiselect.js directive here is required changes from line @252

```
  scope.focus = function focus() {
    var searchBox = element.find('input')[0];
    //searchBox.focus();
  }
```

[image: It cause the move focus up.]

Comment: Comment out @252 line from multiselect.js i.e searchBox.focus().